# How to be integrated within the category of razor view?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to dress category into view. How can I do it? ParentID 1 is the main category.

**Database**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ePTR.png

**Menu**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPSPX.png

How to dress categories of transactions in view?

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ISliderRepository _sliderRepository;
    private readonly IRefRepository _refRepository;

    public HomeController(ISliderRepository sliderRepository, IRefRepository refRepository)
    {
        _sliderRepository = sliderRepository;
        _refRepository = refRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Model = new HomePageView
        {
            Slider = _sliderRepository.GetAll().ToList(),
            Ref = _refRepository.GetAll().ToList()
        };

        List<HomePageView> newList = new List<HomePageView>();
        newList.Add(Model);

        ViewBag.SliderLinkActive = "active";
        ViewBag.SliderLinkNoActive = "";

        return View(newList);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.ViewModel.HomePageView>    

<nav class="header__navigation collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="structurepress-main-navigation" aria-label="Main Menu">

        <a class="home-icon" href="index.html">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </a>

        <ul class="main-navigation js-main-nav" role="menubar">
            <li class="menu-item-has-children current-menu-item">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Slideshow</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index_static.html">Static image</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index_video.html">Video background</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="construction-consultant.html">Construction Consultant</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="green-building.html">Green Building</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="laminate-flooring.html">Laminate Flooring</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="house-renovation.html">House Renovation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="general-contracting.html">General Contracting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="metal-roofing.html">Metal Roofing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="news.html">News</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

**HomePageView**

```
namespace Web.ViewModel
{
    public class HomePageView
    {
        public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public List<Slider> Slider { get; set; }
        public List<SliderImage> SliderImage { get; set; }
        public List<Ref> Ref { get; set; }
        public List<RefImage> RefImage { get; set; }
        public List<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
        public List<Setting> Setting { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? "Dress category" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I want to display categories in the view in the database.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/kPSPX.png

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't make it any clearer. In the code you've posted, your navigation is static. Are you trying to replace this with a dynamic navigation rendered based on rows from the category table? If so, then you should handle this in a child action.

Comment: Does this not be done without the use of child List? can you help me?